# Proof of inequality about mutual information

Tags: information-theory

There is some joint distribution of random variables $(a, b, c, x, y)$. It is known that
$I(a;b|c) = I(a;c|b) = I(b;c|a) = 0$
It is needed to prove this inequality:
$I(a;b) \leq I(a;b|x) + I(a;b|y) + I(x;y)$ 
I have no idea what to do. I tried to use link between entropy and mutual information and chain rule but without any success. Please help. Thank you in advance.